# Install php 5.3.10 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, php, installation, php5, ubuntu-12.04

I have been trying to downgrade the php version from php 5.4 to php 5.3. I tried removing php5, purging php5 and then reinstalling using "apt-get install php5=5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6", but it did not help, I get a message saying "E: Version '5.3.10-1ubuntu3.3' for 'php5' was not found". Is there a way I can install php 5.3.10 in ubuntu 12.04?

I am using amazon ec2 instances,

Answer (score -1):

if you get the reply that some version was not found, it probably wasn't in the repository.

try doing `apt-cache search php5` to see what versions are available.

Otherwise, if there is no package available, you could add the http://www.dotdeb.org/ repository by doing this: `sudo echo "deb http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`. Then another `apt-get update` and then you should have a php5.3 package available.

Answer (score -1):

For instance, apt-cache policy displays the priorities of package sources as well as those of individual packages. Another example is apt-cache dumpavail which displays the headers of all available versions of all packages. apt-cache pkgnames displays the list of all the packages which appear at least once in the cache.

if you need 5.3.10 you also can compile it as cgi from sources or find deb package using google then you need download it and install using dpkg -i $PACKAGENAME